# An error about Android cursor and listView

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I want to add a number in all listView, these numbers come from the SQLite. I use a for loop to add them, and I use a cursor to get them. The question is when I delete one of them, except the last one, the for loop can't work. I found that there is a function "isNull" for cursor, I want to use it, but it doesn't work.

```
    int itemNum=doListlist.getCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < itemNum; i++){
            if(cursor.isNull(i+1)==false){
                float num=Float.parseFloat(listsDbAdapter.fetchData(tableName, i+1).getString(3));
                float price=Float.parseFloat(listsDbAdapter.fetchData(tableName, i+1).getString(5));
                total+=num*price;
            }
            else {
            itemNum++;
            }
        }
```

If you know the reason why it always error, please tell me, THANKYOU!!!

Comment: I guess the curser is invalidated if you delete one of them. Even though I am not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to do... Maybe you could look here on how to properly use a curser: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/2/

Comment: I just want to know the id is exist at the database or it has been delete and become to null(I guess it'll become to null).

Answer (score 0):

You can understand a Cursor as object that represents a part of the database table in the memory (this memory representation is build according to the parameters of `query` method). Thus, a Cursor is a Table with the number of columns (you define these columns in the `query` method) and a number of rows in this table.

When you work with Cursor you sequentially read these rows. Then in these row you operate with columns values.

The statement `cursor.isNull(i+1)` means that in current row you consider `i+1` column and check if the value in this column is null.
So I guess your for loop is not proper. You should navigate through the cursor using `moveToNext()` methods of cursor.

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer. I think i know it better and I'll try it again.

Answer (score 0):

try this `
 int itemNum=doListlist.getCount();
if (cursor!= null) {

```
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {



    for(int i = 0; i < itemNum; i++){

            float num=Float.parseFloat(listsDbAdapter.fetchData(tableName, i+1).getString(3));
            float price=Float.parseFloat(listsDbAdapter.fetchData(tableName, i+1).getString(5));


cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
```

Comment: thank you answer me. I think i get the real reason for this question.